# Getting Private Method error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller:

```
class StatsController < ApplicationController

  require 'time'

  def index
      @started = "Thu Feb 04 16:12:09 UTC 2010"
      @finished = "Thu Feb 04 16:13:44 UTC 2010"
      @duration_time = stats_duration(@started, @finished)
  end

  private
  def stats_duration(started, finished)
    time_taken = distance_of_time_in_words(Time.parse(started), Time.parse(finished))
    time_taken
  end

end
```

It takes in a `start` and `end` time and calculates the duration between the times.

When I run this I get the following error:

> private method `gsub!' called for Thu
>   Feb 04 16:12:09 UTC 2010:Time

Why is this happening?

Comment: You're calling pipeline_duration, but shown us the method stats_duration.  It would help to know which line caused the exception, and if that line is not in your code, which line of your code had been most recently executed.

Comment: This is literally all I get from the console.  I am presuming it is the call to Time.parse.

Comment: Somewhere there will be a stack trace.  Perhaps in a log file somewhere.  We will need that.

Comment: Apologies on the method name, I have now ammended it.  I am trying to find the log output and will post it shortly.

Comment: Although it shouldn't be the cause of the error I presume you also have some code to make the helper method `distance_of_time_in_words` available in your controller?

Comment: @mikej Yea, distance_of_time_in_words is view helper, moved that to the view. thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**private method gsub! called** when using `Time.parse` usually means that you have called `parse` with a `Time` object rather than a `String` so it sounds like your code is actually trying to parse the time twice.

e.g.

```
>> t = Time.now
=> Fri Feb 05 13:12:17 +0000 2010
>> Time.parse(t)
NoMethodError: private method `gsub!' called for Fri Feb 05 13:12:17 +0000 2010:Time
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:965:in `_parse'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/time.rb:240:in `parse'
        from (irb):6
```